# Flipping card state with Redux - should it be stateful component?

Tags: json, reactjs, redux, state

I have a JSON file with a objects in it that have many properties and I would like to display them on a grid of cards (this I have done).

Now I would like to be able to click on a card and display something else on the clicked card (but still staying in the grid view) > basically like turning the card around to display more information.

Would I do this by adding an additional isFlipped boolean property to my JSON objects so I can change it through Redux actions, or should I create a stateful card component? What is best practice?

Comment: Please provide minimal code snippet which you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a presentational component for your card that receives an isFlipped property and a flipCard function.  This component can make the determination of what to render based on the properties it has been given.  If isFlipped is true, render the other information.  Otherwise, render the standard data.  On some event, like onClick, invoke the flipCard function.

Then generate a container component by connecting it to state, mapping isFlipped from some part of your store and an the dispatch of the flipCard action.  If multiple cards can be flipped, you'll need to map flipped card in some sort of a collection, like an object map.  A card would be considered flipped if its key existed in the map.

Wherever your flippable cards need to be rendered, render the container.

Comment: If the flipped state of a card doesn't need to be persisted, keep it out of your data and use state to manage that.

Comment: Thank you, this method worked. I passed an isFlipped array down through my redux state, that stored all the ids of the cards that have been flipped. The component checks if its id is in this array and presents the card accordingly. The onClick calls an action that changes the state.isFlipped array by pushing in its index.